# Gridview improving perfomance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview in my page and a datatable with 1000 rows in it .now i can bind gridview with datatable intwo different ways

1. bind datatable directly to gridview.
2. create another datatable with first ten rows and bind it to grid. on the next page request bind next 10 rows to gridview.

now my question is, does my second aproach really help me to improve perfomance of the page?

Comment: This not help, this optimization are all ready exist on GridView. From you side just take care the correct sql

Comment: or you can replace the gridview with repeater, which is match faster

Comment: Bind is not an issue, the issue is how quickly you can retrieve those 1000 rows.

Comment: when i bind 1000 rows in my first methode i believe it will take much time to load the page. and when i bind it ten by ten i can load the page first time real fast.

Comment: I don't see why it is taking long with only 1k rows. To be honest, I don't think that it should take long even if these 1k rows are being rendered in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to improve the performance in this case:

1. Enable [paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your GridView

   - Advantage: easy to implement, you don't need to change your DataSource
   - Disadvantage: You need to select all records from dbms
2. [Page the DataSource itself(f.e. SQL-Server)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-vb)

   - Advantage: Very fast and scalable
   - Disadvantage: More time-consuming to implement

With only 1000 rows i would recommend to enable paging in GridView.

Comment: but the first load of gridview will be reall slow

Comment: @Athul ks: If GridView's `AlloPaging` is set to `true` and you  only show f.e. 10 rows per page, it should not be slow. But if it's too time consuming to select the 1000 rows from database, you should consider to optimize your dbms(f.e. add indices), your SQL query or implement my second approach(f.e. via SQL-Servers [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)). Then you are only selecting parts.

Comment: @Athul: To avoid misunderstandings: I would drop you approach to split the DataSource in memory. This has two disadvantages: 1. You need to select all rows from dbms anyway 2. You need to store it somewhere(f.e. Session) to benefit from it. This is not very scalable and needs a lot of memory. Besides your data might be outdated.